# USA - Undergraduate Final Transcripts and PhD Programs

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, undergraduate, grades

I am curious about how final transcripts play a role in a graduate program that has already accepted you. For example, if a student with a 3.02 cumulative GPA was accepted into a Physics Ph.D. program that requires a 3.0 cumulative GPA, but does poorly during their last semester of undergraduate classes so their cumulative GPA falls to a 2.98 while still passing all their classes.  Would this student be subject to rejection from the Ph.D. program if they were already accepted into?

I am not in this situation, I am just curious what the implications are for doing poorly on your last semester of an undergraduate degree after having already been accepted into a Ph.D./Masters program.

Thank you!

Comment: Tangentially related: in the UK at least such requirements are sometimes set by the funding body and not the university, so if you don't meet the conditions of the offer you will no longer be funded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "laws" that describe what schools can do in such situations. Everything depends on how strictly the department obeys whatever regulations are in place. Some may say it only counts when the decision is made, and others will insist on it being valid at the time of degree completion. Many schools do not have strict GPA cutoffs for admission, in which case the issue is moot.

In general, though, I don't think I've heard of a school withdrawing an offer because of a small change in GPA. Usually it's when someone contracts "terminal senioritis" and has their GPA fall drastically after the admission offer is made.